# How to add dynamically rows using ajax return type is json with first row position? In JQgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

**Step 1 :** Default list of data populate in table.

**Step 2 :** after every 30 min once i have check using polling ajax method DB and append new list with old list.

Am not able to append first and sorting also not working.

*ajax polling bind the data working but append in last row.*

Please help me.

**table code is below**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#list5").jqGrid({
        url: 'server.php?q=2',
        datatype: "json",
        colNames: ['Inv No', 'Date', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Notes'],
        colModel: [{
            name: 'id',
            index: 'id',
            width: 55
        }, {
            name: 'invdate',
            index: 'invdate',
            width: 90
        }, {
            name: 'name',
            index: 'name',
            width: 100
        }, {
            name: 'amount',
            index: 'amount',
            width: 80,
            align: "right"
        }, {
            name: 'tax',
            index: 'tax',
            width: 80,
            align: "right"
        }, {
            name: 'total',
            index: 'total',
            width: 80,
            align: "right"
        }, {
            name: 'note',
            index: 'note',
            width: 150,
            sortable: false
        }],
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        pager: '#pager5',
        sortname: 'name',
        autoencode: true,
        loadonce: true,
        sortable: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        jsonReader: {
            repeatitems: false,
            id: "ID"
        },
        multiselect: false,
        subGrid: false,

        caption: "Simple data manipulation",
        editurl: "someurl.php"
    }).navGrid("#pager5", {
        edit: false,
        add: false,
        del: false
    });
});
```

**Poll ajax method is below**

```
function poll() {

    var pollOutputJson;
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: server.php ? q = 5,
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            pollOutputJson = data;
            var samGrid = jQuery("#list5");
            var su = samGrid.jqGrid('addRowData', 0, pollOutputJson);
            samGrid.setGridParam({
                rowNum: 15
            }).trigger("reloadGrid");
        },
        error: function (x, e) {
            alert("error occur");
        }
    });
    setTimeout((function (param) {
        return function () {
            poll();
        };
    })(), 180000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need define the rowid of input data. The grid have the option `jsonReader: {repeatitems: false, id: "ID"}` and the column having `name: 'id'`. It means that every item of input data have to have unique `"ID"` property and should have additional `"id"` property. It seems strange.

Seconds, if you add new row using `addRowData` method you should use rowid as the first parameter. In your case the rowid will be specified by `"ID"` property of input data. So you should use something like `data.ID` as the first parameter of `addRowData` method. The code which you posted don't contains any clear description of the response from URL `"server.php?q=5"`. If the input data is **one item** of data then the code should be `samGrid.jqGrid("addRowData", data.ID, data)`. On the other side if `data` is **array of items** having `"ID"` as the property which specify the rowid then you should use `samGrid.jqGrid("addRowData", "ID", data)` to add the multiple rows.

The next problem which you have to solve is validation of rowid duplicates. Let us `"server.php?q=5"` returns one item to simplify the situation at the beginning. Is it possible that the item with the same ID property already exist in the grid? In the case you have to use `setRowData` instead of `addRowData` to modify/replace existing row instead of adding row and getting id duplicates which is not allowed in HTML.

One more problem in your question. You wrote that you don't want to append the data as the last row. On the other side you wrote that you want to have **sorted** data. So the position of the added data should depend on contain of `name` column (you use `sortname: 'name'` option).

Probably the most simple way to implement autorefresh of data by replacing **all data** in the grid. In the way the possible merge (modification of existing data) will be done on the server and the server could just return the full set of current data. Because you use `loadonce: true` then `datatype` of grid will be change to `"local"` after the first loading from the server and so you can work with the grid like with the grid having local data. It means the `data` parameter with array of items exist in the grid. by usage of

```
var intData = $("#list5").jqGrid("getGridParam", "data");
```

you get **the reference** to internal array with the data. Using

```
success: function (data) {
    var $mygrid = $("#list5"),
        allGridParams = $mygrid.jqGrid("getGridParam");
    allGridParams.data = data;
    $mygrid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{current: true}]);
}
```

Because `$("#list5").jqGrid("getGridParam")` represent the reference to **all internal parameters of jqGrid** the line `allGridParams.data = data;` replace old internal data to another array of items. The next line reload local grid. It means that the data will be sorted by `sortname` and the first page of the size specified by `rowNum` will be displayed. The option `{current: true}` of `reloadGrid` will try to select the same row after reloading which was selected.

Of cause you have to fix syntax error in your code (the line `url: server.php ? q = 5,` should be replacted to `url: "server.php?q=5",`) and you have to move the lines

```
setTimeout((function (param) {
    return function () {
        poll();
    };
})(), 180000);
```

**out of** body of the `poll` function.

Comment: Oleg please help me.......Above function working fine if am integrating list of list json with poll list to not working the sub grid data am using beforeProcessing: function (data) {, integrating link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25284441/how-to-populate-list-of-list-json-in-jqgrid-that-is-list-for-main-grid-under-li

Comment: @KrishnakumarSubbaiyan: It should work. It you have implementation problems you should open new question where you post the code which you use now and which not work like you expect.

Comment: Oleg Thanks,i will post new question then after you will clear.

Comment: Oleg,I have post new question please check below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508527/how-to-populate-subgrid-while-polling-ajax-then-apppend-existing-grid-in-jqgrid