# I want cliend side pagination/sorting? search in server side in jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I want client side pagination/sorting and column filter data fetch from server side. i have use polling server side ajax call [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25261997/how-to-add-dynamically-rows-using-ajax-return-type-is-json-with-first-row-positi) and push the data to client side .But i change the **loadonce : false** to get data from server side its use full for column filter for my grid. if loadonce :true all the call's are client side sorting and paging so not able to achieve the column filter server side.

I want client side pagination/sorting with server side column filter

Please help me.

```
jQuery("#list451").jqGrid({ 
url:'getList.php?mode=result_list', 
datatype: "json",
height: 255, 
width: 600, 
colNames:['Index','Name', 'Code','Result'], 
colModel:[
{name:'item_id',index:'item_id', width:65, sorttype:'integer',searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','le','lt','gt','ge']}},
{name:'item',index:'item', width:150, sorttype:'string',searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','bw','bn','cn','nc','ew','en']}},
{name:'item_cd',index:'item_cd', width:100} ,
{name:'result',index:'result', width:100,sorttype:'string',searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne']} ], 
rowNum:50, 
rowTotal: 200,
rowList : [20,30,50], 
loadonce:false, 
mtype: "GET", 
rownumbers: true,
rownumWidth: 40, 
gridview: true, 
pager: '#pager451', 
sortname:'item_id', 
viewrecords: true, 
sortorder: "asc", 
caption: "Loading data from server at once" });
jQuery("#list451").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{searchOperators : true});
```

Polling code is below

```
function poll() {

var pollOutputJson;
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: server.php ? q = 5,
    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        pollOutputJson = data;
        var samGrid = jQuery("#list5");
        var su = samGrid.jqGrid('addRowData', 0, pollOutputJson);
        samGrid.setGridParam({
            rowNum: 15
        }).trigger("reloadGrid");
    },
    error: function (x, e) {
        alert("error occur");
    }
});
setTimeout((function (param) {
    return function () {
        poll();
    };
})(), 180000);
}
```

Comment: Please inform me the reason.... if you are put minus mark in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to comment `function poll` which code I find very suspected. I wanted just answer on your main question about usage of `loadonce: true` with client side pagination/sorting, but loading filtered data (by `filterToolbar`) from the server.

You need just use `beforeSearch` callback of `filterToolbar` to reset `datatype` to `"json"`.