# free-jqGrid (4.15.4), server filter, client sorting and paging?

Tags: javascript, c#, free-jqgrid

Attempting to load data from server based off of multisearch/filters, but do sorting and paging on client.  i have found a few posts that say to simply set the datatype back to the original value in the `beforeSearch` method.

i have attempted this and it does execute against the server and return the correct data.  However, the second time i filter it seems to get the data from the server but then it gets wiped out on line 4429 in the jqgrid code shown below.  Any idea on how to achieve this goal?

> Ln 4429 : p.lastSelectedData = query.select();

grid definition:

```
$element
    .jqGrid({
        cmTemplate: { search: true, searchoptions: { attr: { placeholder: "filter..." }, clearSearch: true }, sortable: true, align: "center" },
        colModel: [
            { name: "Id", key: true, hidden: true, searchoptions: { searchhidden: true, sopt: ["eq"] } },
            { name: "TransmissionId", label: "Transmission Id", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq"] } },
            { name: "Name", label: "Name", searchoptions: { sopt: ["cn"] } }
        ],
        datatype: "json",
        loadonce: true,
        height: "auto",
        ignoreCase: true,
        pager: $("#" + pagerId),
        pgbuttons: true,
        pginput: false,
        rowList: [10, 25, 50],
        rowNum: 10,
        toppager: true,
        url: "url here",
        loadComplete: function (data) {
            if (this.p.datatype === "json") {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $element.trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: 1 }]);
                }, 50);
            }
            return data;
        },
        viewrecords: true
    })
    .jqGrid("filterToolbar", {
        autosearch: true,
        defaultSearch: "cn",
        beforeSearch: function () {
            $element.setGridParam({ datatype: "json", page: 1 });
        }
    })
    .jqGrid("navGrid", "#" + pagerId, {
        edit: false,
        add: false,
        del: false,
        refresh: false,
        view: false,
        cloneToTop: true
    });
```

I have trimmed down the grid to try to verify it is not custom logic that is causing this issue.  the grid does have `multipleSearch` on. but is not defined above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question then you should use `forceClientSorting: true` in combination with `loadonce: true`. It force that the data loaded from the server will be sorted, filtered and paged **locally** directly after loading from the server. Thus you can remove `loadComplete`, which you use currently. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46330312/315935) for a demo.

Additionally, you can add `searching` property, where you include all options of `filterToolbar` and `searchGrid`:

```
searching: {
    autosearch: true,
    defaultSearch: "cn",
    beforeSearch: function () {
        var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam"), // get reference to all parameters
            filters = JSON.parse(p.postData.filters);
        p.datatype = "json";
        // one can here analyse filters, modify it or clear it as
        p.postData.filters = "";
        // one can set any other parameters, which will be sent to the server
        // by using p.postData.param1 = "value1";
        // which will sent param1=value1 to the server.
    }
}
```

In general you can do the same inside your current `beforeSearch` too.

**UPDATED:** Probably you should use `beforeProcessing` callback additionally. `beforeProcessing` will be called directly after receiving the data from the server. Inside of the callback you can clean-up all `p.postData.filters` (to `""`) and `p.search` (change it from `true` to `false`). As the result jqGrid will **not** try to filter **locally** by `postData.filters` the data returned from the server.

Comment: I am looking to only sort/page client side.  the filter i intend to send to the server to get a different data set back to the client.

Comment: @XBiLe: I still don't understand your current problem. `filterToolbar` fills `postData.filters` and calls `beforeSearch`. You can make **any changes** in `postData`. Then `filterToolbar` sets `search: true` and trigger `reloadGrid`. If `datatype` is changed from `"local"` back to `"json"` then jqGrid will send `postData` to the server (your `url` of the grid). So you can full customize the data, which will be sent to the server. Is it what you asked?

Comment: Sorry, not trying to make this confusing.  The goal is to use the filters to query a new dataset from the server, but page and sort locally on the browser.  The ask [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26017378/i-want-cliend-side-pagination-sorting-search-in-server-side-in-jqgrid) is pretty much the same.  my problem is the second time i get data from the server, the method `addLocalData` triggers `query.select()` which removes the new dataset.  I am stepping through the eval, but it looks like the execute `match` is not null (Ln 2034)

Comment: @XBiLe: It's difficult to help you without having the demo, which reproduces the problem. The line `p.lastSelectedData = query.select();` is sure not the origin of your problem. Probably you should use `beforeProcessing` callback additionally. It will be called directly after receiving the data from the server. Inside of the callback you can clean-up all `p.postData.filters` (to "") and `p.search` (change it from `true` to `false`). As the result jqGrid will *not* try to filter *locally* by `postData.filters` the data returned from the server.

Comment: i stepped through the jqgrid JS and found what causes the data to be lost in my example.  It is the jlinq processing, one of my filter fields is a bool and during eval it does `String(jQuery.jgrid.getAccessor(this,'IsSuccess') || '').toUpperCase()` which results in an empty string because of a `false` bool filter value.

Comment: i will try your latest suggestion and see how it goes.

Comment: i am still trying to get a example created as time has not allowed me to dedicate time to it.  in any case, the original question as to why the data was being wiped out was because of the local search attempting to validate a bool column definition.  by setting `p.search = false` the local search is not applied and the issue is resolved, or i could have set the `sorttype: "boolean"` and fixed it that way as well.  i do have other questions, but will wait until i have a demo.  thanks Oleg.